# Знаки препинания в предложении.

Tags: синтаксис

Наличие тишины в городе, где  потерянным людям необходимо прятаться в шуме это наказание. 
Что ставим перед "это"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед "это" надо поставить запятую и тире.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая показывает конец придаточного предложения, а тире между подлежащи и сказуемым в главном.